# Как правильно внести значение просмотров в лист

Tags: c#, парсер

тренируюсь в написании html парсера суть работы в том что бы вытащить с сайта инфу о сериалах а именно Названия / URL постера / Просмотры, с названием и URL постера все прошло гладко но на просмотрах у меня всё встало не получается занести их в список.
сделал как смог, но все просмотры съехали на одну позицию вниз, как можно поправить?

```js
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
 
namespace ConsoleSimpleHTMLParser
{
    #region 
    // Базовый класс, в котором храняться название тайтла, ссылки на постер и колличество просмотров.    
    class SeriesData
    {
        public SeriesData(string t, string up, string v)
        {
            Title = t;
            UrlPoster = up;
            View = v;
        }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string UrlPoster { get; set; }
        public string View { get; set; }
    }
 
    class Series : SeriesData
    {
        public Series(string t, string up, string v) : base(t, up, v)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
 
    // Класс SeriesList способен управлять любым видом списков сериалов.
    // при условии, что он является производным от класса SeriesData.
    class SeriesList<T> where T : SeriesData
    {
        T[] serList;
        int end;
 
        public SeriesList()
        {
            serList = new T[10000];
            end = 0;
        }
 
        // Добавить элемент в список.
        public bool Add(T newEntry)
        {
            if (end == 10000)
            {
                return false;
            }
 
            serList[end] = newEntry;
            end++;
            return true;
        }
 
        public void Insert(string inst, int count)
        {
            try
            {
                serList[count].View = inst;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                count--;
                serList[count].View = inst;
            }
        }
 
        public void ShowList()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < end; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Название: {0} \nURL Постера: {1}\nПросмотры: {2}\n", serList[i].Title, serList[i].UrlPoster, serList[i].View);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
 
    class Program
    {
        static string LoadPage(string url)
        {
            var result = "";
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
 
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                if (receiveStream != null)
                {
                    StreamReader readStream;
                    if (response.CharacterSet == null)
                        readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
                    else
                        readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
                    result = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                    readStream.Close();
                }
                response.Close();
            }
            return result;
        }
 
        static void Main()
        {
            SeriesList<Series> serieslist = new SeriesList<Series>();
 
            // Загрузить html из сети интернет
            var pageContent = LoadPage(@"https://web.archive.org/web/20190926110623/https://animevost.org/");
            var document = new HtmlDocument();
            document.LoadHtml(pageContent);
 
            // Загрузить html локально
            //HtmlDocument document2 = new HtmlDocument();
            //document2.Load(@"H:\sample.txt");
 
            HtmlNodeCollection infoSeriesTitleURLPoster = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//td/div/a/img");
            HtmlNodeCollection infoSeriesView = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//div/div[2]/div[2]/span[1]");
 
            foreach (HtmlNode item in infoSeriesTitleURLPoster)
            {
                serieslist.Add(new Series(item.GetAttributeValue("title", "").Replace("&quot;", ""),   // название
                                          item.GetAttributeValue("src", ""),                           // url постера
                                          item.GetAttributeValue("span", "")));                        // просмотры
            }
            int count = 0;
            foreach (HtmlNode item in infoSeriesView)
            {
                serieslist.Insert(item.InnerText, count++);
            }
            serieslist.ShowList();
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Во первых: Перестаньте обращаться по индексу к "ноде", это не правильно! То есть это `.//div/div[2]/div[2]/span[1]` у вас должно превратиться в что-то по типу этого: `//div[@id='dle-content']...`, где `...` - это дальше необходимые элементы, которые находятся внутри `<div id="dle-content">`. Другими словами ищите нечто уникальное на странице (id/class), а не по индексам берите, ибо если сайт например вставит рекламу перед вашим `div[2]`, то он уже будет не 2 по индексу, а 3 и все ваше приложение перестанет работать, а отладить это будет довольно трудно и затратно по времени.

Comment: почему бы не использовать список вместо этого `serList = new T[10000];`?

Comment: Во вторых: Вы из общего HTML документа берете 2 совершенно не связанных друг с другом объекта (картинки: `".//td/div/a/img"` и 
информацию: `".//div/div[2]/div[2]/span[1]"`). Берите сразу нужные объекты и их преобразуйте в классы. Вот смотрим страницу, ищем нужную там информацию и видим, что все разделено на блоки, некие [объекты](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8nuP.png), они повторяются и их там как видите много. Значит уже можно написать `SelectNodes("//div[@class='shortstory']")`, что выдаст вам все посты со страницы, остается пройтись по ним циклом и распарсить уже внутреннюю информацию.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я рассуждал как вы но у меня не хватило экспириенса и в ход пошли костыли)

Comment: Ну вы спрашивайте что вам надо, мы поможем, научим. А пока вы походу из за этих костылей и страдаете, ибо из за несвязанности объектов они походу и съезжают. У вас тут должен быть по сути 1 цикл `foreach`, да и какой смысл в `SeriesList` мне тоже не понятен, ибо тут простой `List<>` подойдет.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ идея была такая, вывести информацию о сериале а именно Название/URL Постера/ Количество просмотров в виде таблицы которую я в последствии сохраню в excel [мой проект](https://b.radikal.ru/b30/2001/54/f9d2a1647304.png)

Comment: Так вперед. У вас есть класс `SeriesData`, делаете простой `List<SeriesData>`. Дальше из HTML получаете все посты страницы (показал выше), ну и проходитесь по ним циклом, где каждую итерацию парсите текущий HTML "поста", формируете `SeriesData` и добавляете в лист. Например получение заголовок поста будет примерно таким: `var title = post.SelectSingleNode("./div[@class='shortstoryHead']/a").InterText;` Тут я [взял](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQVkh.png) в текущем посте (объект цикла) элемент `div` с классом `shortstoryHead` и в этом `div`-е взял `a`, из которого просто взял текст.

Comment: У вас должно быть примерно что-то на подобие [этого](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SXZwqT), только вместо вывода на экран делаете класс и добавляете его в коллекцию, а дальше уже с полученными объектами делайте все, что вам нужно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо за столь исчерпывающие объяснения, пойду дальше практиковаться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давно не пробовал Html agility pack, но что-то типа такого:

```
var series = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='shortstory']");

foreach (HtmlNode item in series)
{
    var title = item.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='shortstoryHead']/h2/a")?.InnerText;
    var posterUrl = item.SelectSingleNode(".//img[@class='imgRadius']")?.GetAttributeValue("src", "");
    var views = item.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='staticInfoRightSmotr']")?.InnerText;

    var element = new Series(title, posterUrl, views);
    serieslist.Add(element);
}
```

Выводит без сдвигов:

```
Название: Кандагава: Девушки на гидроциклах / Kandagawa Jet Girls [1 из 12+] [2 серия - 15 октября] 
URL Постера: /web/20190926110623im_/https://animevost.org/uploads/posts/2019-09/1569439519_1.jpg
Просмотры: 15138

Название: Маг-обманщик из другого мира / Isekai Cheat Magician [1-12 из 12] 
URL Постера: /web/20190926110623im_/https://animevost.org/uploads/posts/2019-07/1563784705_01-1.jpg
Просмотры: 3578543

Название: Рыцари усердия / Try Knights [1-9 из 12+] 
URL Постера: /web/20190926110623im_/https://animevost.org/uploads/posts/2019-08/1565134513_1.jpg
Просмотры: 310173

Название: Рыцари усердия / Try Knights [1-9 из 12+] 
URL Постера: poster_url
Просмотры: 310173
```

Как работает — смотрите объяснения в комментариях EvgeniyZ, он всё правильно вам сказал.

Comment: Раз `.FirstOrDefault()` (один элемент), то тогда уж `.SelectSingleNode()` - вернет первый, подходящий элемент, а не коллекцию.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Точно, а я ещё пытался вспомнить, как же в этой библиотеке будет получение элемента. Да, так будет гораздо чище код. Спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь, разобрался как это все работает)